# Change header when on home page

Tags: homepage, headers

Im trying to make my home page have one type of header which is different from every other page.
I have made a page the front page in the settings called home and in header.php i have changed the code to this:

```
<?php if(is_home()) {?>
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php echo "Hello World" ?>"/></a></h1>
        </hgroup>
    <?php } else {?>
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/Cranbri-web-solutions.png"/></a></h1>
        </hgroup>
    <?php } ?>
```

Can anyone see whats wrong? because for some reason the header inst changing??

Thanks

Comment: use `is_front_page()` instead, or target the actual page id and use `is_page($x)` where `$x` is the id of the page in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a static page as the front page, use `is_front_page()` instead of `is_home()` in the condition.

Comment: Perfect thankyou! Been a while since i have used wordpress!